# How to update an acf field after clicking a submit button?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to update text to an acf field after clicking a submit button.
The field is empty at the moment and I need to update text into the existing field.
I added the following code in a post edit page but it doesn’t update the value.
Would you please let me know how to fix the code?

I created the button below using acf widget in elementor:

```
<input type="submit" class="acfef-submit-button acf-button button button-primary" data-state="publish" value="EDIT">
```

I added the following code in a post edit page:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_infosubmission_field');
function update_infosubmission_field($post_id) {

$post_id = get_the_id();
$field_key = "field_606cb980986773";
$value = "yes";

update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try with removing `$post_id =get_the_id();`

Comment: Hi Gautam: I've just tried but still it doesn't save the value...

Comment: It is `get_the_ID();` not `get_the_id();`

Comment: Hi Vel: I tried get_the_ID(); but still doesn't save the value.

Comment: If it is not working than there is possibility that your action is not calling. Can you confirm that your action is calling. And you said that you have added Button using acf widget in elementor what does it have to do with this ?

Comment: @GautamGolakiya:I’m a beginner so I’m not so sure how the submit button and the acf code work. So, I added both codes. Would you please let me know how to check if my action is calling, if possible?

Comment: @Vel: Sorry but would you please let me know how to share the plugin url? I'm a beginner and I've never shared it before...

Comment: change this `add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_infosubmission_field');
` to `add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_infosubmission_field', 20);`

Comment: @Vel: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: change this `add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_infosubmission_field');
` to `add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_infosubmission_field', 20);`

Comment: @Vel: I changed it to add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_infosubmission_field', 20); but still doesn't update the value... And I didn't created  type="submit", the plugin automatically created it...

Comment: can you share me the screenshot of admin?

Comment: @Vel: I'm not sure which part, do you mean this one? https://i.imgur.com/rfEvO6L.jpg

Comment: you need to add this code to functions.php. Also please share the screenshot of edit post with your custom field. And remove this line `$post_id = get_the_ID();`

Comment: @Vel: I added it to a post edit page, and now I deleted it then added it to functions.php, but still it doesn't update... https://i.imgur.com/XxEATbx.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/binzJ7h.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/znOdTks.jpg

Comment: its working fine for me https://imgur.com/jhXKaik. share you me your full code?

Comment: Just to be clear you are updating post from edit page. Right ?

Comment: @Vel: Oh.... I don't have other code, the codeve above is the one that I'm using now. Could you let me know your code? So that I can copy and paste them?

Comment: @GautamGolakiya: Yeah, I added the php code in a edit page (I'm not sure if I have to add it to the edit page though). I can also add it to a function.php as long as it works..

Comment: Create a custom field https://imgur.com/n4IPQHL. the go to edit post. then inspect your custom field and find the name of the your custom field. https://imgur.com/HbfOyaA

Comment: @Vel: I created and used the key field : https://i.imgur.com/znOdTks.jpg .. Phew ... I don't know why it doesn't work for me .. Maybe, I should use acf/edit_post instead of acf/save_post? I tried it but still doesn't work..

Comment: please check `field_606cb980986773` key. field key is wrong as per your screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/znOdTks.jpg. its end with `693`

Comment: @Vel: Thank you a lot for your help and explanation. Now it works. You were a big help. I learnt a lot from you : )

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: @GautamGolakiya: Thank you for your help and the comments. You were right, I delete $post_id = get_the_ID(); and added it into function.php and it works now. Thank you again : )

Comment: @Vel: thank you again for your patience, take care Vel : )

Comment: @Aino, you are welcome.

Comment: @Aino, you need always `yes` for the field?

Comment: @Aino Glab we can help you. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case for someone who may need it.
The following code works:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_name');
function update_name($post_id) {

  if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'infosub') {
    return;
  }
    
$field_key = "field_606cb980986773";
$value = "yes";

update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Really helped me.